# Scifi short story - "Look, darling. Food!"

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Read this a long time ago so is not a recent output, may not even have been a good story but has been nagging me that I cannot remember its name or much of the contents! Basically deals with a space ship that has some sort of incident in space meaning they are stranded with limited supplies, there is a mother and her baby on board who becomes the dominant character and basically, the end of the story has the rescuers arriving to be greeted by those two, no one else, and the mother saying something about look darling, food when she sees the rescuers.

Comment: Can't think of the title or author at the moment, but it's been made into at least 2 different radio productions, one of them for BBC Radio 4's 'Fear on 4'.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128509/need-help-to-find-a-sci-fi-collection-i-read-at-school-mid-80s (question about a collection mentioning this story)

Comment: probable duplicate of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/166750/short-story-where-a-lady-survives-in-a-lost-spaceship (which is newer and has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 17):

It is ['Survival' (1952) by John Wyndham](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57823). It's appeared in multiple collections as well as having some adaptations for radio (including [BBC Radio Fear on Four](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b007jnpz))

Comment: There's a review containing the line at https://doomsdayer.wordpress.com/2013/04/23/wyndham-john-survival-1952/